# local position to global position

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, 3d

I have an object which I am tracking with a Kinect2 depth camera. From this I create an object with a position(vector3) and orientation(vector4 or quaternion).
If I create a position and orientation for my Kinect sensor, how can I then derive a global coordinate for my tracked object?

I am using c#. Currently my application uses WPF

I have this method, but it doesn't seem to translate the output at all

```
private Vector3D LocalToGlobal(Vector3D localVector)
    {
        SensorUnit sensor = this.area.SensorUnits.ElementAt(0);
        Vector3D outVec = localVector;
        Matrix3D sensorMatrix = new Matrix3D();
        sensorMatrix.Translate(sensor.Position);           

        Vector3D.Multiply(outVec, sensorMatrix);
        return outVec;
    }
```

Comment: Multiply the object's position with the sensor's transformation matrix.

Comment: Thanks, how can I derive a transformation matrix from a position vector and rotation quaternion?

Comment: You can also transform the position directly with the quaternion (and add the translation vector).

Comment: Ok, given a position and a rotation, how can I get this into a matrix format that will allow me to quickly make the conversion to global space?

Comment: [Convert Quaternion to Matrix](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToMatrix/)